# Access to global object in php

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller

I have small snippet (**My index page**):

```
require 'app.php';
$app = new AltoRouter();

$app->setBasePath(CMS_BASE_DIR);
$app->map('GET|POST','/', 'home@index', 'home');

$match = $app->match();
if ($match) {

    list($file, $method) = explode("@", $match['target']);

    $class = ucfirst($file).'Controller';

    if(is_callable(array($class, $method))) {
        $object     = new $class();
        call_user_func_array(array($object, $method), array($match['params']));
    } else {

        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found", true, 404);
        exit();
    }

} else {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found", true, 404);
    exit();
}
```

**My HomeController**

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        Auth::checkAuthentication();
    }

    public function index() {}
}
```

How can I use $app object in my models/views/controllers.
How can I set $app as global?

Thanks!

Comment: `$GLOBALS['app']`, or `global $app`, basically.

Comment: Or better pass it in to `__construct()`, or use `AltoRouter::doSomething()` or `$app = AltoRouter::getInstance()`.  global is probably not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

if you're always going to use it in this object type, then you can make it a parameter for your constructor function:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    private $app;

    public function __construct($app_p) {
        parent::__construct();
        Auth::checkAuthentication();
        this->app = $app_p;
    }

    public function index() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These previous approaches are fine in your case, but you should consider to dive deeper in OOP and stop doing  function calls outside of classes or reaching for stuff like core classes from controllers.

Go with the answer by Jeff